# Tag clean up request - [repeating]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There is a [repeating](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/repeating) tag.

It doesn't seem to be very useful, almost a meta tag.

It's only on 16 questions (at the time of writing) so should be easy to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Went ahead and cleaned them all up! :)